# How to build a LaTeX live preview of a textarea which contains a python expression using sympy in Django?

Tags: python, django, sympy, mathjax

I would like to create a form on my site built with Django, that would ask for a python expression, with a live LaTeX previewing of this expression.
Let me precise the steps :

1. The expression would initially be a string (TextField)
2. I convert it in a python math expression with the eval() sympy function.
3. Sympy converts it in LaTeX code with the latex() function.
4. **get a live previewing of this LaTeX code (with MathJax ?)**

Any idea ?

Comment: I tried something similar with Flask. I was too lazy to figure out MathJax so instead I just had the Jinja HTML: `<img src="{{ img_url }}">` where `img_url = f"http://mathurl.com/render.cgi?{urllib.parse.quote(sympy.latex(expression))}%5Cnocache"`. I would really like to hear an answer using MathJax so I'm rather leaving my option as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I'm gonna think about an ajax script to call my python function on my server and use it in my javascript code.